# Expressing ethnicity that is different from nationality

Tags: word-choice

How do you go about expressing ethnicity that is different from your nationality.

I happen to be of British decent from Canada (now living in Japan):

```
イギリス系のカナダ人です。
```

That's my best guess. Any improvements?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Possibly related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5795/91

Comment: You can leave out the の. `イギリス系カナダ人` sounds a tad more natural to me.

Comment: From the 在日韓国人 wikipedia page it suggests ethnic Koreans with Japanese nationality are 日本籍コリアン and not 韓国系日本人. Wonder if there are more exceptions

Comment: The word 在日 is used for people of either Korean or Chinese decent in Japan, especially the former.  While the word itself just means "staying in Japan," so 在日アメリカ人 for Americans living in Japan should make sense, such usage is rare and even awkward (to my ears).  The word 在日 is frequently used by the jingoistic Japanese to refer to the said groups of people in quite derogatory manner, so depending on the occasion you may need to be aware of the subtleties the word could bring to in your conversations.  For the original question, イギリス系カナダ人 would be the most natural way; no need for の there.

Comment: @Everybody, please answer in the answers.  Comments can be removed or hidden arbitrarily, and people with the same question in the future may not know to look in the comments for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the best way is

> イギリス系カナダ人

if your nationality is Canadian but you are of British descent.  Using の in between is okay and perfectly makes sense, but in many cases it will lead to an excessive use of の.  For example, if you are an British Canadian engineer, then

> イギリス系のカナダ人のエンジニア

sounds a bit awkward but

> イギリス系カナダ人のエンジニア

is pretty much perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

> イギリス生まれのカナダ人

It's a bit longer, but should be clear that you were born in England but are Canadian (if this is the case).