# I'm half and a Japanese man said to me: 「ハーフ憧れる」What does it mean?

Tags: nuances

I understand that 憧れる is "to respect, long to be like." Are there such connotations associated with being "half" in Japan?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the Japanese stack exchange. Unfortunately [we are not a bulk translation service](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and so won't be able to answer questions for you unless you can provide some evidence of research and some guesses about what this might mean, or what parts in particular you are struggling with.

Comment: It's one of the compliments that some Japanese like to give. Something along the lines of 日本語、上手！ I call it お世辞。

Comment: The title seems to be opposite to yours though, there seems to be similar discussion here: [Is the word ハーフ derogatory?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/898/is-the-word-%e3%83%8f%e3%83%bc%e3%83%95-derogatory). Is it helpful?

Comment: @Mindful I think this question is specifically about the connotation of the word ハーフ.

Comment: @naruto it is now. Edit made it much much clearer.

Comment: Is my understanding of 憧れる correct in this context?

Comment: @Mindful I didn't notice that, sorry. ＠Ellie, Basically yes, but I feel "to long to be like" might be a bit too strong in this context. Perhaps something along the lines of "that's cool" might be enough.

Comment: @naruto no worries, easy to miss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there such connotations associated with being "half" in Japan?

Different people have different opinions here, but in general, yes. ハーフ (especially Western-Japanese "half") is commonly associated with beauty and proficiency in languages, and there are a few people who actively seek international marriage. Please see the link posted by @kimiTanaka, too.